# DD-WRT auto connect to phone hot-spot when available

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection, dd-wrt

Here's my situation: My router, **running dd-wrt is set up to connect to my phone's hot-spot**.

In general it is working well. The small problem is, obliviously the phone (4G) hot-spot it's not always available. (When hot-spot is not available there is no other wan connection).

When the phone's hot-spot becomes available, (turned on or gets in range) the router does not always connect to it automatically. Sometimes it does, sometimes I have to reboot it.

I did not set the **Proxy Watchdog Service** to prevent the router interface from hanging or rebooting when the hot-spot is not available. 
Is there a way to improve the auto-reconnect?

---

<sup>*</sup> TP-Link TL-WR841N 
** Wireless Physical Interface is set to client mode

Comment: @Tim_Stewart  TP-Link TL-WR841N

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I guess it can detect being off - line. I am not sure how it can detect that the hot-spot is available.  If it does, can you post the script  ?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, thank you. I'll have to learn to use a script. I never had the need yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find the script that I had customized for my buffalo N-finity's. I probably deleted them when i upgraded & gave the routers to a friend.

This is a script that I found on the DD-WRT forums for this purpose.
(**You will probably have to tinker with this script for your router model**)

A couple of things to note:

- The router needs to have accurate time, make sure to set it up under the main setup tab, all the way at the bottom. (**I use pool.ntp.org**) You may have to save apply and reboot for it to take effect.
- The system logs must be turned on and functioning under **services tab -> system log -> syslogd enabled**
- This script checks the /var/log/messages folder to determine time and error messages. telnet or ssh into the router, check the log with `tail -25 /var/log/messages` and make sure there is output from the router in there. If not a reboot may be required.
- You need to change the wireless interface in the script to reflect your routers interfaces names. most Broadcom interfaces will be "**wl0**" and most Atheros interfaces will be "**ath0**". you can find the names under the wireless tab in the web-GUI, or in the terminal with **ifconfig**.
- Change the wait times to reflect the amount of time you actually need for your situation. I would think 2-3 mins would be acceptable in your situation.

**By m1st0, 2011 with input from http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Buffalo_WZR-HP-G300NH**

```
#! /bin/sh

# Or just put it in the nvram startup
#nvram set rc_startup='{The Rest of this script}'

# set up variable to track waiting times
restarted_wifi=false
# Check interface every minute
logger "Starting to check wifi status"
while sleep 50; do
  restarted_wifi=false
  # Check for the most recent message of WiFi dropping out, unsure if it is the same as the other hang below
  test_time=`date  +"%b %e %H:%M" | cut -c1-11`
  test_message=`grep "$test_time" /var/log/messages`
  test_wifi_down=`echo $test_message | fgrep ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
  test_beacon_issue=`echo $test_message | fgrep "Resetting; Code: 01"`
  if [ -n $test_wifi_down ];
  # If found then restart the WiFi interface
  then   logger "Wifi hang, restarting";
   ifconfig ath0 down;
        sleep 4;
        ifconfig ath0 up;
        restarted_wifi=true
        test_wifi_down=""
  # Check for the most recent message of WiFi hang, unser if it is the same as the dropping above
  elif [ -n $test_beacon_issue ];
  # If found then restart the WiFi interface
  then
   logger "Wifi becon issue, restarting";
   ifconfig ath0 down;
        sleep 4;
        ifconfig ath0 up;
        restarted_wifi=true
        test_beacon_issue=""
  fi;
  # Wait a long while before we check again since we just restarted
  if [ $restarted_wifi == "true" ]; then
        logger "Will wait 542 seconds before checking wifi again";
        sleep 542;
        restarted_wifi=false;
        logger "Will start to check wifi every 50 seconds again";
  fi
done
```

Judging by the rep you have over at stack overflow, I think you will have no problems manipulating this script for your purposes. If you run into trouble just shoot me a message.

Some of [these scripts](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Useful_Scripts#Automatic_Connection_Repair) may also be useful to you.